# What is the alternative to --resultlog in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Since the --resultlog option is deprecated in pytest, what are the alternative options available for logging test results?"

```
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --resultlog=result.log log
```

Comment: whats a result log?

Comment: Good question. The argument was not removed from the docs! See https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/output.html#creating-resultlog-format-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pytest` is currently in version 7.1.2, and the `resultlog=` argument [was removed in v6](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#result-log-result-log), which was released in July 2020.

The replacement is to [install `pytest-reportlog`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-reportlog) which adds the `--report-log` option and uses a JSON-format log.

```
pip install pytest-reportlog
pytest --report-log=result.log # and whatever else
```